# jQuery Ripple effect in Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

Is it possible to show water ripple effect in android using this [jQuery code](https://github.com/sirxemic/jquery.ripples/)

I want it to run in HTC One M8 phone only. When I pulled the code from the git and hosted it in my server, the same works fine in Android webview. But adding the jQuery code to assets folder and loading it from there is not showing the effects.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Enable javascript in your webview. This could be the reason your Jquery is not working in webview.

```
WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```